# Sometimes getting cannot read property issue after page load due to which some functionality affected

Tags: javascript, magento-2.2.5

On the entire website(homepage, category page etc) sometimes I'm getting **"cannot read property timepicker" issue** due to which some feature like **"Add To Quote"** functionality affected & instead of "Add to Quote" item via AJAX it's redirecting to 404 page.

**Please visit the following screesnhot:-**

When "Add To Quote" feature is working :-

[image]

**When "Add To Quote" feature not working :-**

[image]

**Note:-1** I'm using some 3rd party extensions on the site also migrated from Magento1 to 2, using custom theme etc.

**2-**

I need to run only "Add to Quote" feature so please let me know how i can resolve  " cannot read property" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the JavaScript try catch in the part of the code that is giving the above error as

```
try
{
// code with the possibility of throwing a js error
}
catch (err)
{
// your error handling js code
}
```

Also add a code to check if the particular js variable is defined or not as below code:

```
if (typeof yourvariable !== 'undefined')
```